# Finding area of polygons within buffer

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, area, overlapping-features

I have 102 different sites in two cities, which I have created buffer zones for.

I also have layers that have polygons for different landscape features (e.g. water surface area).

I am trying to find a way to find the area of the polygons within each individual buffer, so that I can conduct statistical analysis to determine if the area of each landscape feature differentiates two groups of sites.

I am new to GIS, and so far have been able to narrow down the extent of some polygons to those that occur within the buffer zone, but not being able to differentiate between each individual site. I used Vector *Selection > Extract by location > Extract from: vegetation, by comparing: buffer zone*.

I would ideally like to produce a spreadsheet with each individual site, with the area of each polygon type within that buffer zone. Is it possible to keep the labels of the sites within the results as well? I am hoping to collate this information into a spreadsheet and run it through R for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Overlap Analysis` tool from Processing toolbox. Search for Overlap in the processing toolbox, and it should appear.

> This algorithm calculates the area and percentage cover by which
> features from an input layer are overlapped by features from a
> selection of overlay layers.

[image]

If all the buffer polygons are located in one polygon layer, you can use the iterator - the green icon - to iterate over each individual polygon in the layer.